# Add class to div when user scroll down

Tags: jquery

i need to Add class to div when user scroll down, this is my code:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() { 
   $("#skin_h").removeClass("skin");
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (scroll <= 75) {
      $("#skin_h").addClass("skin_srolld");
   }
});
```

```css
.skin {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
}


.skin_srolld {
    top:500px!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="skin" id="skin_h">
</div>
```

its not work some help with this please.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$` with window object it will not work since window is a normal javascript object and not a jquery

```
window.scroll(function() { 


$("#skin_h").removeClass("skin");
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (scroll <= 75) {
      $("#skin_h").addClass("skin_srolld");
   }
});
```

This should work :)

Answer (score 0):

i figure it out the correct code is

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
 $(window).scroll(function() {
     var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

     if (scroll >= 60) {
  $(".skin").addClass("skin_srolld");
     } else {
  $(".skin").removeClass("skin_srolld");
     }
 });
});
```